# How do you disassemble an overloaded operator in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

If I have something like bool operator ==(const uint128& x, const uint128& y);  how can I get gdb to disassemble it?

Comment: How's uint128 implemented?  If it's a built-in integral type, then you can't define an operator==

Comment: It's defined as a struct of two unsigned long longs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(gdb) p 'operator==(uint128 const&,uint128 const&)'
$1 = {bool (const uint128 &, const uint128 &)} 0x401040 <operator==(uint128 const&, uint128 const&)>
(gdb) disassemble $1
Dump of assembler code for function _ZeqRK7uint128S1_:
0x00401040 <_ZeqRK7uint128S1_+0>:       push   %ebp
... (elided)
0x00401066 <_ZeqRK7uint128S1_+38>:      ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Comment: Gives me "unmatched single quote."  I tried it with double quotes too and no quotes, no dice.

Comment: Try it w/ "p" instead of disassemble.  Then pass the address to disassemble.

Comment: How do I get the address of the function?

Comment: Aha, yes indeed, I was including the variable names, that's the problem.  Thanks!